# Google Maps Infowindow in multiple marker

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'am trying to create GIS web using google maps api v3, JSON, and postgresql. i can show multiple marker in mymap, but when I click on a marker and try to open the Info window only the last marker will response correctly.

The problem is if i try and assign content to the infowindow within a loop. Then when i click the marker, it only knows about the content from the very last iteration of the loop. i know the problem but don't know how to solve it. sorry for my bad english. any suggestion?
here the code (json.php and index.php):

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT distinct org_id, customer_name, attribute16, attribute17 FROM gis where org_id = 41 OR org_id = 124";
    $data = pg_query($sql);
    $json = '{"enseval": {';
    $json .= '"customer":[ ';
    while($x = pg_fetch_array($data)){
        $json .= '{';
        $json .= '"id_customer":"'.$x['org_id'].'",
            "nama_customer":"'.htmlspecialchars($x['customer_name']).'",
            "x":"'.$x['attribute17'].'",
            "y":"'.$x['attribute16'].'"
        },';
    }
    $json = substr($json,0,strlen($json)-1);
    $json .= ']';
    $json .= '}}';

    echo $json;
?>



    <html>
    <head>
    <title>contoh</title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- load googlemaps api dulu -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var peta;
    var gambar_tanda;
    gambar_tanda = 'assets/img/marker.png';
    var x = new Array();
    var y = new Array();
    var customer_name = new Array();
    function peta_awal(){
        // posisi default peta saat diload
        var lokasibaru = new google.maps.LatLng(-6,107);
        var petaoption = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: lokasibaru,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        peta = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),petaoption);
        // memanggil function ambilpeta() untuk menampilkan koordinat
        ambipeta();
    }

    function ambipeta(){
        url = "json.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg){
                for(i=0;i<msg.enseval.customer.length;i++){
                    x[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].x;
                    y[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].y;
                    customer_name[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].x),parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].y));
                      tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: point,
                                map: peta,
                                icon: gambar_tanda,
                                clickable: true
                    });
                //here is my problem    
                var isi = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:isi
                });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(tanda, 'click', function() {
                    //infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(peta,tanda);
                    });

                }
            }
        });
    }
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body onload="peta_awal()">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">CONTOH</a>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px"></div>

    <hr>
          <footer>
            <p>&copy; TEST</p>
          </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah i solve this problem. here is the code :
 hope this case can help someone.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>contoh</title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      body {


padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- load googlemaps api dulu -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize(){
    var peta;
    var gambar_tanda;
    gambar_tanda = 'assets/img/enseval.jpg';
    var x = new Array();
    var y = new Array();
    var customer_name = new Array();

        // posisi default peta saat diload
        var lokasibaru = new google.maps.LatLng(-6,107);
        var petaoption = {
            zoom: 6,
            center: lokasibaru,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        peta = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),petaoption);
        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                          content: ""
        });


        // memanggil function ambilpeta() untuk menampilkan koordinat
        url = "json.php";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg){
                for(i=0;i<msg.enseval.customer.length;i++){
                    x[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].x;
                    y[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].y;
                    customer_name[i] = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].x),parseFloat(msg.enseval.customer[i].y));
                      tanda = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: point,
                                map: peta,
                                icon: gambar_tanda,
                                clickable: true
                    });
                bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer);
                //var isi = msg.enseval.customer[i].nama_customer;
                //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                //google.maps.event.addListener(tanda,'click', function() {
                //return function(){
                //infowindow.setContent(this);
                //infowindow.open(peta,this);
                //};
                //});
                /*var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:isi
                });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(tanda, 'click', function() {
                    //infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(peta,this);
                    });*/

                }
            }
        });
    }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        function bindInfoWindow(tanda, peta, infowindow, strDescription) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(tanda, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
            infowindow.open(peta, tanda);
        });
    }
    //onload="initialize() -- > body
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body ">  
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                    </a>
                <a class="brand" href="#">CONTOH</a>
                <div class="btn-group pull-right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px"></div>

    <hr>
          <footer>
            <p>&copy; TEST</p>
          </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```